# Mi simulación no actualiza los cambios. Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle

Amigos estoy iniciando en la programación, quizás es una novatada pero no sé qué hacer. Cuando arrancó el simulador del IDE no me muestra los cambios realizados. Ya refresqué en Gradle. Reinicié el IDE, el simulador y nada. No actualiza los cambios. Qué podrá ser?

Comment: estás programando aplicaciones android o aplicaciones Java normales?

Comment: En aplicaciones android.

Comment: A mi el simulador de android studio me solia dar muchos fallos(no cargaba bien, era lento,etc), te recomiendo que utilices tu propio movil conectado por USB [aqui te dejo una pagina donde te explica como hacerlo](https://androidstudiofaqs.com/tutoriales/conectar-movil-android-studio)

Comment: Sí amigo, es un error frecuente, yo uso mi móvil conectado por usb. Para ello debes ir a ajustes> Información > número de compilación (Aquí darle varias veces seguidas click), de esta forma se habilitará el modo desarrollador.
Regresas a ajustes y verás en la parte inferior una nueva opción que dice: Modo desarrollador.
Entras y activas el modo "Depuración Usb".
Es todo. Conectas a tu android y podrás usar tu móvil para las pruebas. Nota: Debes tener los drivers (controladores) de tu celular instalados en tu pc.
Para instalarlos hay varios tutoriales y dependen de la marca de tu celular.
Suert

Comment: Si arranca el simulador  pero no muestra los cambios puede ser un problema del ADB, en realidad no esta subiendo la actualización del .APK a tu emulador, te sugiero agregues más detalles, revisa la consola o el LogCat.